# SVG: Select by class, html with javascript jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Years back, Dan Miller had [the same problem](https://gist.github.com/dmill109/1944049), as I have now, as they wanted a function (JavaScript) to get SVG elements by class. Dan proposed a function, but users were unable to run it:

```
function getSvgElemByClass(svgRoot,classSearchStr) {
// modification of Dustin Diaz's find by class script - http://www.dustindiaz.com/getelementsbyclass/
    return( 
        function getSvgElementsByClass(searchClass,node,tag) {
            var classElements = new Array();
            if ( node == null )
                node = document;

            if ( tag == null )
                tag = '*';

            // SVG = XML, so we need the XML method:
            // using 'magic' namespace variable provided by websvg (svgns)
            var els = node.getElementsByTagNameNS(svgns,tag);
            var elsLen = els.length;
            var pattern = new RegExp('(^|\\\\s)'+searchClass+'(\\\\s|$)');

            for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
                // SVG specific helper
                if(els[i].hasAttribute('class') &&
                    pattern.test(els[i].getAttribute('class')) ) {
                        classElements[j] = els[i];
                    j++;
                } else if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) ) {
                    classElements[j] = els[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            return classElements;
        }
    )(classSearchStr,svgRoot)
}
```

An .svg file could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   id="svg1024" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20" height="20">

<style id="style_css_sheet" type="text/css">

.land
{
   fill: #00ff00;   
   stroke-width: 0.2;
   stroke: #e0e0e0;
}
.aa, .ab
 {
   fill:       #ff0000;
  }
  </style>

  <g class="land bg"
  id="A">
    <path d="M 0,5 H 5 V 0 H 0 Z"
       id="aa" class="land er bg"/>
    <path d="m 10,5 h 5 V 0 h -5 z"
       id="ab" class="land er bg"/>
    <path d="m 5,5 h 5 V 0 H 5 Z"
       id="ac" class="land tt bg"/>
  </g>
  <path d="M 0,10 H 5 v -5 H 0 Z"
     id="ba" class="land er au"/>
  <path d="m 10,10 h 5 v -5 h -5 z"
     id="bb" class="land tt au"/>
  <path d="m 5,10 h 5 v -5 H 5 Z"
     id="bc" class="land er au"/>
  <path d="M 0,15 H 5 V 10 H 0 Z"
     id="ca" class="land tt bg"/>
  <path d="m 10,15 h 5 V 10 h -5 z"
     id="cb" class="land tt au"/>
  <path d="m 5,15 h 5 V 10 H 5 Z"
     id="cc" class="land er bg"/>
</svg>
```

1. From html I would like to select by class, like select all class "tt", or select all class "au". Tried with the script of Dan Miller, tried to fix it, but could not do it.
2. I would like to override the values set in the svg. (change .land {fill: #00ff00;})

I use this script

- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.5/svg.js

So that I can draw by id. That works, if I remove the `.land{...}`:

```
var element = SVG.get('fi');
element.fill('#f06')
```

How could I select by class? What to do, so that I can leave default colouring (`.land{...}`)?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use jQuery to change the fill by class:

```
$('.land').css('fill', '#0000ff')
```

Working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gazdagergo/pen/YOKROx).

Answer (score 0):

You mention jQuery in your title, but later just Javascript.

jQuery is not required.  Modern browsers have the `document.getElementsByClassName()` method.

```js
var  tt = document.getElementsByClassName("tt");
Array.from(tt).forEach(function(item) {
   item.style.fill = "#0000ff";
});
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   id="svg1024" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20" height="20">

<style id="style_css_sheet" type="text/css">

.land
{
   fill: #00ff00;   
   stroke-width: 0.2;
   stroke: #e0e0e0;
}
.aa, .ab
 {
   fill:       #ff0000;
  }
  </style>

  <g class="land bg"
  id="A">
    <path d="M 0,5 H 5 V 0 H 0 Z"
       id="aa" class="land er bg"/>
    <path d="m 10,5 h 5 V 0 h -5 z"
       id="ab" class="land er bg"/>
    <path d="m 5,5 h 5 V 0 H 5 Z"
       id="ac" class="land tt bg"/>
  </g>
  <path d="M 0,10 H 5 v -5 H 0 Z"
     id="ba" class="land er au"/>
  <path d="m 10,10 h 5 v -5 h -5 z"
     id="bb" class="land tt au"/>
  <path d="m 5,10 h 5 v -5 H 5 Z"
     id="bc" class="land er au"/>
  <path d="M 0,15 H 5 V 10 H 0 Z"
     id="ca" class="land tt bg"/>
  <path d="m 10,15 h 5 V 10 h -5 z"
     id="cb" class="land tt au"/>
  <path d="m 5,15 h 5 V 10 H 5 Z"
     id="cc" class="land er bg"/>
</svg>
```